# Splitting a SetterBar to multiple lines, wrapping at a given page margin?

Tags: gui-construction, display, interactive, user-interface, pagelayout

I have 4 SetterBars linked to the same variable, and representing 593 choices in four categories.  How might I get a sensical output that wraps to window or screen or some arbitrary margin?

```
SetterBar[Dynamic[firstchoice], Range[1, 43]]
SetterBar[Dynamic[firstchoice], Range[44, 131]]
SetterBar[Dynamic[firstchoice], Range[132, 358]]
SetterBar[Dynamic[firstchoice], Range[359, 593]]
```

I thank you in advance,

F.

Comment: use the option `Appearance _>'Row"`? (i.e., `Column[{SetterBar[Dynamic[firstchoice], Range[1, 43], 
   Appearance -> "Row"],
  SetterBar[Dynamic[firstchoice], Range[44, 131], Appearance -> "Row"],
  SetterBar[Dynamic[firstchoice], Range[132, 358], 
   Appearance -> "Row"],
  SetterBar[Dynamic[firstchoice], Range[359, 593], 
   Appearance -> "Row"]}]`)?

Comment: ...or `SetterBar[Dynamic[firstchoice], Range[593], Appearance -> "Row"]`?